# APPLICATION_OVERLAY doesn't take inputs on Android 13

Tags: android

I am building an overlay UI for my app. The UI takes inputs and works as expected on android <= 12 but on android 13 it becomes unresponsive. The exact same code/build works on Android 12 but not on 13. This is the code using which I am creating the overlay:-

```
View test = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test, null, false);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params =
    new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.OPAQUE);

windowManager.addView(test, params);
```

I have ensured that the app has "Draw over other apps" permission.

The android 13 behaviour change [page](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-all) also doesn't mention anything around APPLICATION_OVERLAY.

Comment: I have this very same problem, background freezes on Android 13 when using FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE and therefore click events won't go throught. Works on Android 12. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Try these flags comination:**

```
new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                width,
                height,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: Didn't help, I have a popup window that my app displays over Android phone UI when someone is calling, but answering/declining the call requires two clicks (first one hides the popup). In earlier Android versions one click would be enough and popup stays on top during the call. Don't know what changed in Android 13.